# Adempiere - Dynamic Approval in Workflow based on Organization

Tags: adempiere

I plan to implement this for Requisition document.

So, I have 8 users, each from different Organizations. 
There are 3 Organization.

```
1. General Organization
Users : 
  1) G0
  2) G1a
  3) G1b

2. Finance Organization
Users :
  1) F1
  2) F2

3. Technical Organization
Users :
  1) T0
  2) T1a
  3) T1b
```

Assuming that I am user `G0`, I have 4 Approvals. They are from :

```
1. G1a
2. G1b
3. F1
4. F2
```

And, assuming that I am user `T0`, I also have 4 Approvals. They are from :

```
1. T1a
2. T1b
3. F1
4. F2
```

So I need to have permission from people in my organization first (depends on who login) before the approval from people in Finance Organization.

How can I make it possible in Adempiere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Standard Approval* in *Adempiere* requires the **Supervisor** of a **User** approve any value above the **Approval Amount** of the user's **Role**.

However, as you have no doubt discovered, it only allows for one supervisor approving.

To achieve what you need is a little trickier and you will need to use the **Workflow** functionality of *Adempiere*.  There are a number of steps involved and they're described in this [howto](http://wiki.adempiere.net/How_to_Configure_Dynamic_Approval_Workflow) from the *Adempiere* wiki.